# counting rows returned in postgresql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, rowcount

I need to count the number of rows returned from database.By  using following code

```
rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM AA where name = 'active '") 
rv[0]["id"]
```

works when some values are returned but I need to check if no values are returned: Can someone help please.

Comment: It might have helped to emphasize that this is PL/Python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`.rowcount`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)

Comment: This is correct in DB-API, but not in PL/Python, which is what is being used here.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just check the size of the rv array?

Comment: I am quite new to postgresql, can you please tell how to check the size of rv array. That will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thats not postgres related, it's standard python syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use -

```
SELECT Count(*) as rowCount FROM AA where name = 'active'
```

This will return you the number of rows from the query. If there are no rows, then it will return 0.

Comment: because he is looking to get something not just count. Additionally needs to know whether or not there was any result. Using your method would take 2 queries.

Answer (score 3):

In PL/Python, the way to get the result size is

```
rv.nrows
```

See the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html).